# Python Code Error when creating new module

Tags: python, module, odoo

I have created a new module in OpenERP through eclipse here is my python code

```
   from osv import osv, fields
   class asset_allocation(osv.osv):
      _name = 'asset.allocation'
      _description = 'Asset Allocation'
      _columns = {
         'asset_id': fields.many2one('account.asset.asset', 'Asset', required=True),
         'employee_id': fields.many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee', required=True),
         'asset_status': fields.date.time( 'Status', required=True,),
         'note': fields.text('Note'),
      }

   asset_allocation()
```

but in first two lines error occurs
ERROR

```
Unresolved import: fields
Undefined variable from import: osv
```

any help please?

Comment: I've never heard of osv, what package is it?

Comment: it is kepler ........

Comment: Make sure you are running this code in openerp, not directly in eclipse.

Comment: This code does not represent `Module`. In terms of OpenERP it's a `Model`.

Comment: In which folder did you create this module? Is your Eclipse project set up correctly to run OpenERP - are you able to start OpenERP from Eclipse? Could you give the entire error message?

Comment: in eclipse -addon i create module .... it show me error in class

Comment: @user3044672 Have you created `__openerp__.py` `__init__.py` files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
```